# Dynamic-programming matrix exercise

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

I'm practicing with dynamic programming and I'm trying to solve this exercise http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collect-maximum-points-in-a-grid-using-two-traversals/ But I can't understand how to use dynamic programming.

My reasoning is to use a table `T[n][m]` to store the results and in every cells to find the max value to go (corresponding to a cell).

Using the example shown in the link: how do I know at the first cell `[0][0]` to go to "**3**" instead of "**5**"? Using my reasoning the choice is to go to "**5**" but it's a bad way

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about how to know which route to choose, you need to make the choice that will maximize your accumulated score.  So in your example, if you're trying to decide between a route that gives you 5 and one that gives you 3, you will choose the greater one (5).

Your reasoning on using a table to utilize dynamic programming for this problem is correct.  As you calculate the values of the table, fill them in.  When you come across a calculation you've already performed and stored into your table, you'll be able to just access the previously stored calculation at that cell in your table rather than computing it a second time.